# Disable button until one radio button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm busy on a registration, and I want people to choose their gender. I do this by the use of radio buttons. Now, what I want, is to have a disabled `post` button untill one of the two boxes is selected, this I do with jQuery:

```
var $radio = $("input:radio");
$radio.change(function() 
{
    var checkedButtons = false;
    $radio.each(function() {
        if (this.checked) 
        {
            var checkedButtons = true;
            return false;
        }
    });
if (checkedButtons)
{
    $("#postGender").removeAttr("disabled");
}
    else
{
    $("#postGender").attr("disabled", "disabled");
}
```

});

This little piece is code, was found by me on stackoverflow. The only thing wrong is that it doesn't work.

See this for more code and ofcouse a demo: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n6sta3dp/)

Comment: I don't understand why people downvoted this, in learning phase everyone could just miss the detail..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could reduce all that to one line:

```
$("input:radio").change(function () {$("#postGender").prop("disabled", false);});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/n6sta3dp/1/)**

Comment: Or if you prefer, 
    $("input[type=radio]").one("click", function() {
        $("#postGender").prop("disabled", false);
    });

Comment: @Dave: by [`one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/), did you mean [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)?

Comment: .one() should work fine since you only need to clear it as soon as a radio is selected.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `var` within the first `if` block. `var checkedButtons = true;` is creating a *different* `checkedButtons` within the scope of that block. So the first `checkedButtons` will be unchanged, and the other is gone once the `if` block is finished.

It should just be `checkedButtons = true;`

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify this greatly.

If you think about it, once they click on a radio button, they can't really deselect it: they can only click on another radio button. So, once the button has changed once, there's really no need to monitor it anymore and you can just enable the button from there.

```
$("input:radio").change(function () {
    $("#postGender").attr("disabled", false);
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/n6sta3dp/7/)

Comment: The added explanation above is nice.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do:

```
var $radio = $("input:radio");
$radio.change(function () {
    if ($radio.filter(':checked').length > 0) {
        $("#postGender").removeAttr("disabled");
    } else {
        $("#postGender").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n6sta3dp/8/

A few sidenotes:

- Once a radio button has been checked, it can never be unchecked by the user (unless he starts using the js console). I think it would be safe to remove the 'else' part in your function.
- Don't forget that a form can also be submitted by using the enter key, so just disabling the button will not be enough. You should probably listen for the submit event of your form as well and check if the user made a choice before letting the submit go trough.