# jQuery multi-step form: disable 'next' button until input is filled in each section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I have a multi-step form with different input types inside each `<fieldset>`. I have a 'next' `<button>` which will trigger the next section of the form once the current fieldset has been completed.

Currently the next button is set to `disabled` until the user has met the criteria for that fieldset - ie: checked radios/checkboxes etc.

The issue I'm having is the jQuery I'm using to switch the button attribute to `.prop('disabled', false);` changes all of the buttons in the entire form to `false`. Is it possible to target the `<button>` within the current fieldset only?

Additionally, is it possible to disable the next button if a user goes back to a section and unchecks all inputs?

Here's a previous answer containing the script i'm currently using: [Disable button until one radio button is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581407/disable-button-until-one-radio-button-is-clicked)

I have a Codepen with a prototype of what I'm working on here: https://codepen.io/abbasarezoo/pen/jZgQOV - you can assume once live each one fieldset will show at a time.

Code below:

HTML:

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <h2>Select one answer</h2>
        <label for="radio-1">Radio 1</label>
        <input type="radio" id="radio-1" name="radio" />
        <label for="radio-2">Radio 2</label>
        <input type="radio" id="radio-2" name="radio" />
        <label for="radio-2">Radio 3</label>
        <input type="radio" id="radio-3" name="radio" />
        <br />
        <button disabled>Next</button>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <div class="radio-group">
            <h2>Select one answer per row</h2>
            <h3>Row 1</h3>
            <label for="radio-4">Radio 1</label>
            <input type="radio" id="radio-4" name="radio-row-1" />
            <label for="radio-5">Radio 2</label>
            <input type="radio" id="radio-5" name="radio-row-2" />
            <label for="radio-6">Radio 3</label>
            <input type="radio" id="radio-6" name="radio-row-3" />
        </div>
        <div class="radio-group">
            <h3>Row 2</h3>
            <label for="radio-7">Radio 1</label>
            <input type="radio" id="radio-7" name="radio-row-4" />
            <label for="radio-8">Radio 2</label>
            <input type="radio" id="radio-8" name="radio-row-5" />
            <label for="radio-9">Radio 3</label>
            <input type="radio" id="radio-9" name="radio-row-6" />
        </div>
        <button disabled>Next</button>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <h2>Select multiple answers</h2>
        <label for="checkbox-1">Checkbox 1</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1" name="checkbox" />
        <label for="checkbox-2">Checkbox 2</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-2" name="checkbox" />
        <label for="checkbox-2">Checkbox 3</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-3" name="checkbox" />
        <br />
        <button disabled>Next</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$('fieldset').click(function () {
    if ($('input:checked').length >= 1) { 
        $('button').prop("disabled", false);
    }
    else {
        $('button').prop("disabled", true);
    } 
});
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

i have just change your js into this .. this will help you to enable current button in the fieldset not all of them

```js
$('fieldset').click(function () {
 if ($('input:checked').length >= 1) { 
  $(this).closest('fieldset').find('button').prop("disabled", false);
 }
 else {
  $('button').prop("disabled", true);
 } 
});
```

Comment: I was editing the question as your answer came through. Is it possible to disable the next button if a user goes back to a section and un-checks all input inside that particular section?

Comment: yes definitely .. your code will also disable it if the user will go back and uncheck the box it will be again prob the button  .

Comment: Jasper - I've set up a prototype here: https://codepen.io/abbasarezoo/pen/jZgQOV 

When you select a checkbox in the first fieldset, the button becomes active. And when you select a checkbox in the second fieldset it also becomes active.

The issue i'm having is when you de-select the checkboxes in each section, the button remains active. Is there a way to disable the button when no fields are selected?