# jQuery multi-row form: disable submit until each row has a radio checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, radio-button

I have a multi-row form with single choice radio buttons in each row. I'd like the final `<button>` tag to be disabled until a radio button as been checked from each row.

I currently have a solution from a previous question ([jQuery multi-step form: disable 'next' button until input is filled in each section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49149392/jquery-multi-step-form-disable-next-button-until-input-is-filled-in-each-sect)) that removes the `disabled` attribute from the button when you select any radio button but i'd like to be more specific if possible.

Is this possible? Here's a Codepen of what I'm working on currently: https://codepen.io/abbasarezoo/pen/vdoMGX - as you can see when hit any radio in any row the disabled attribute comes off.

HTML:

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <div class="radio-group">
            <h2>Select one answer per row</h2>
            <h3>Row 1</h3>
            <label for="radio-1">Radio 1</label>
            <input type="radio" id="radio-2" name="radio-row-1" />
            <label for="radio-2">Radio 2</label>
            <input type="radio" id="radio-2" name="radio-row-2" />
            <label for="radio-3">Radio 3</label>
            <input type="radio" id="radio-3" name="radio-row-3" />
        </div>
        <div class="radio-group">
            <h3>Row 2</h3>
            <label for="radio-4">Radio 1</label>
            <input type="radio" id="radio-4" name="radio-row-4" />
            <label for="radio-5">Radio 2</label>
            <input type="radio" id="radio-5" name="radio-row-5" />
            <label for="radio-6">Radio 3</label>
            <input type="radio" id="radio-6" name="radio-row-6" />
        </div>
        <button disabled>Next</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$('fieldset input').click(function () {
    if ($('input:checked').length >= 1) { 
        $(this).closest('fieldset').find('button').prop("disabled", false);
    }
    else {
        $('button').prop("disabled", true);
    } 
});
```

Comment: Your radio buttons should have identical names per row, because now they don't work as supposed to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the same name for the radio button group so that only one radio button is selected per row. Then, you can simply compare the length of the checked radio button with the length of the radio button group like this,

```js
$('fieldset input').click(function () {
    var radioLength = $('.radio-group').length; 
    if ($('input:checked').length == radioLength) { 
        $('fieldset button').prop("disabled", false);
    }
    else {
        $('button').prop("disabled", true);
    } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <div class="radio-group">
            <h2>Select one answer per row</h2>
            <h3>Row 1</h3>
            <label for="radio-1">Radio 1</label>
            <input type="radio" id="radio-2" name="radio-row-1" />
            <label for="radio-2">Radio 2</label>
            <input type="radio" id="radio-2" name="radio-row-1" />
            <label for="radio-3">Radio 3</label>
            <input type="radio" id="radio-3" name="radio-row-1" />
        </div>
        <div class="radio-group">
            <h3>Row 2</h3>
            <label for="radio-4">Radio 1</label>
            <input type="radio" id="radio-4" name="radio-row-2" />
            <label for="radio-5">Radio 2</label>
            <input type="radio" id="radio-5" name="radio-row-2" />
            <label for="radio-6">Radio 3</label>
            <input type="radio" id="radio-6" name="radio-row-2" />
        </div>
        <button disabled>Next</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: $(this).closest('fieldset').find('button').prop("disabled", false); this can be simplified like $('fieldset button').prop("disabled", false);

Comment: @Sami thanks for suggestion. I have edited it with your suggested way.

Comment: you welcome :) need an up-vote on the comment please.

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal Nice! This works exactly how I need it to. Do you think this could work for other form elements such as text, email, tel fields? So the disabled attribute wouldn't be removed until all form fields are completed.

Comment: No, this code will not work for all other different HTML form elements. In that case the code will be bit complex and you need to track the elements are filled or not, accordingly.